# TinySort <li> items based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I'm trying to bring all `<li>` items to the top of the list using TinySort:

```
<ul class="team">
    <li><strong>Name 1</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Name 2</strong></li>
    <li class="sticky"><strong>Name 3</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Name 4</strong></li>
    <li class="sticky"><strong>Name 5</strong></li>
</ul>
```

I'm needing to override the order of the list created with PHP. What is the correct jQuery script for doing this when the page loads?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it several ways; one way is to prepend them back to their own list:

```js
$(".sticky").prependTo(".team");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/kUq4p/

Comment: That is an elegant solution. And it doesn't even require TinySort. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this  http://jsfiddle.net/DUZkp/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $tempDiv = $('<div><div/>');

    $('.team li').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('sticky')){
            $tempDiv.append($(this));
        }
    });

    $('.team li').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('sticky')){
             $tempDiv.append($(this));
        }
    });

    $('.team').html($tempDiv.html());

});
```